# Divide terms between two list

Tags: python, list, division

I'm trying to work with two list, both of them with 2000 numbers in it.
I want to divide every term on the first list with the corresponding term in the second list, and save that division in a new list

For example:

```
    first = [1,2,3 ...]
    second = [4,5,6 ...]

    prob = [i/a for i,a in first,second]
```

I would like the result will be:

```
    prob = [1/4,2/5,3/6 ...]
```

But when I do this, I get the error ValueError: too many values to unpack

Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to represent it in the form `1/4`, `2/5`, ... ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `zip`:

```
prob = [i/a for i,a in zip(first,second)]
```

Also, unless you have `python3.x`, the division (`/`) operator will perform integer division. Therefore, if you want float values and you are using python2.x, you should convert one of the values to `float` as follows:

```
prob = [float(i)/a for i,a in zip(first,second)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer but in this case, using `operator` and `map` is probably a faster way:

```
In [16]:

from __future__ import division
import operator
In [17]:

first = [1,2,3]
second = [4,5,6]
map(operator.truediv, first, second)
Out[17]:
[0.25, 0.4, 0.5]
In [18]:

%timeit [float(i)/a for i,a in zip(first,second)]
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.08 µs per loop
In [19]:

%timeit map(operator.truediv, first, second)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.34 µs per loop
```

`numpy` also provide yet another concise way to do it.

```
In [20]:

import numpy as np
arrf=np.array(first)
arrs=np.array(second)
arrf/arrs
Out[20]:
array([ 0.25,  0.4 ,  0.5 ])
In [21]:

%timeit arrf/arrs
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.07 µs per loop
```

It is not the fastest for such a small problem. But might win in big ones.